# coffescript checking if condition in for

Tags: coffeescript

This work expect taking into account `if k isnt 'notifications_table`

```
v for k,v of tablesDict if k isnt 'notifications_table'
```

how to make it work like a python `for` with condition given in `if statment` in same line.

Comment: Something like this where foods is an array of strings:
`eat food for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
v for k,v of tablesDict when k isnt 'notifications_table'
```

Filtering example from the CoffeeScript [docs](http://coffeescript.org/):

```
# Health conscious meal.
foods = ['broccoli', 'spinach', 'chocolate']
eat food for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate'
```